# How to get non zero positive numbers form array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array for which i need to get non zero positive numbers

```
$arr = array(
-100,-2,0,100,1000
);
```

Desire output:

```
$arr = array(
100,1000
);
```

Thank's

Comment: If you have tried something yourself, can you also include your current PHP code?

Answer (score 1):

You could use following code

```
$output = array_map($input, function ($value) {
            if (is_numeric($value) && $value > 0) {
                return $value;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Is this backwards? I also think this will return a null with the array as opposed to just the array sans those values. Not sure what the OP is looking for though.

Comment: @hfw Null is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
$arr = array(
    -100,-2,0,100,1000
    );
$arr =  array_filter($arr, function ($x) { return $x > 0; });
exit(var_dump($arr));
```